# macOS - OS X - Swift 3 - How to know when user zoomed in/out on map?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, mapkit

I'm using MapKit, and I have a map in my macOS application. How do I know when a user zooms in and out on my map?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the app with the MapView and you have the view controller conforming to the MKMapViewDelegate, implement the method below to find out if user zoomed in/out of the map view. But first, in that same method, print out this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    print(mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta)
}
```

That will show the current latitude delta for whatever span you set it at when you move to a region. Mine was around 0.014 everywhere I went to on the map at the same zoom level, so all you need to do is check when the delta is greater than or less than that number as shown below.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    let latitudeDelta = mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta

    if (latitudeDelta > 0.015 || latitudeDelta < 0.014)
    {
        print("User zoomed map")
    }
}
```